# PhoneCallTask alert color change in windows phone 7 & 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

**I am forcing my application only to be in light theme this means even if you select the dark theme from phone settings, you can not see the dark theme. I am pragmatically finding the theme and changing all the styles in to white theme.**

I want my UI in white theme, all the controls, popup, etc will be in white theme.

I am using the PhoneCallTask, the popup is coming up as usual but in dark theme it is showing the black popup, i want the popup color as white color even though dark theme is selected.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing you can do about it. You can force your app to use the white theme, but you cannot for the system "parts" to do so, not even the keyboard.